# How do I determine where the KeyError originates?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple implementation of a (directed) graph in Python 3.x using an adjacency list. To remove an edge of the graph, I'm looking at a function that looks something like this:

```
class Graph(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = {}

    def add_vertex(self, x):
        """ Adds x to the graph, if it doesn't exist """
        if x not in self.vertices:
            self.vertices[x] = set()
        else:
            print("Error: vertex {} already in graph!".format(x))                

    def add_edge(self, x, y):
        """ Adds the edge from x to y, if it doesn't exist """
        try: 
            if y not in self.vertices[x]:
                self.vertices[x].add(y)
            else:
                print("Error: edge already exists!")
        except KeyError:
            print("Error: vertex {} not found!".format(x))

    def remove_edge(self, x, y):
        """ Removes the edge from x to y, if it exists """

        try:
           self.vertices[x].remove(y)
        except KeyError:
           # QUESTION: which part of the try block caused the KeyError?
           print("Error: vertex not found!")
```

My problem is that because I'm using a dictionary of sets, both can raise a KeyError in

```
self.vertices[x].remove(y)
```

If I want to print an error message indicating that one of those two vertices (`x` or `y`) doesn't exist, is there a way of determining which part of the line raised the error? Or do I have to check again and base the error message off the (repeated) check?

(Note: I recognize that there're some logical errors in the code above -- e.g., add_edge needs to check that x and y both exist.)

Comment: Split it into two statements: `temp = self.vertices[x]` and `temp.remove(y)`, each in a separate `try` block.

Comment: @jasonharper: Feel free to make that an answer -- if no one else comes up with something that is shorter/still as easy to read, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why is your graph class taking responsibility for printing error messages? If it's an error to re-add an existing edge or remove one that doesn't exist or whatever, it seems like your graph should be communicating that through exceptions.

Comment: @user2357112: Fair point, but I'm saving those architecture issues for a CodeReview post later. I presume you're saying that I should implement & raise a custom exception?

Comment: @tonysdg: Or ValueError or something.

Answer (score 1):

So first just check whether there presents any node named x in the graph and if it's present then check whether there exist any edge from x to y

```
def remove_edge(self, x, y):
    """ Removes the edge from x to y, if it exists """    
    if x in self.vertices:
        if y in self.vertices[x]:
            self.vertices[x].remove(y)
        else:
            print("There is no edge from x to y")
    else:
         print("There is no node x present in the graph")
```

and if you really want to know according to try catch

```
def remove_edge(self, x, y):
    """ Removes the edge from x to y, if it exists """

    try:
       self.vertices[x]
    except KeyError:
       print("Error: vertex x not found!")

    try:
       self.vertices[x].remove(y)
    except KeyError:
       print("Error: vertex y not found!")
```